# CSS / JQuery List of icons on hover expand left to right

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list which I wrap in a div and float it right:

I need to be able to make the li a expand from right to left like the images below:

[image]

So for the list id do this:

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="btn1.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="btn2.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
#menu-wrapper {float:right;width:40px;}
```

How to I get the list to expant on hover right to left like the image?

Comment: Where is the text coming from? Do you expect to add it with javascript.  This could be done with pure CSS depending on where you add the text (either inside the HTML or with a pseudo element).

Comment: Well, I could add a span to the LI and insert the text there. The text would be fixed not dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `max-width` to give animating effect

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/nature');
  background-size: cover;
}
#menu-wrapper {
  text-align: right;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.cell {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.cell span {
  float: left;
  max-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
.cell:hover span {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="cell">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-icon-set-free-pack/48/Streamline-18-32.png" /><span>expanded</span>
    </li>
    <li class="cell">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-icon-set-free-pack/48/Streamline-18-32.png" /><span>expanded</span>
    </li>
    <li class="cell">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-icon-set-free-pack/48/Streamline-18-32.png" /><span>expanded</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use transitions, here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qyg8zdn/)

```
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="list"></div>

<style type="text/css">
.button {position:relative; width: 40px; height: 40px; float: right; background-color: red; transition: margin-right 1s; z-index: 1000;}
.list {position:relative; width: 100px; height: 40px; float: right; margin-right: -100px; background-color: yellow; transition: margin-right 1s; z-index: 100;}

.button:hover + .list {margin-right: 0px;}
</style>
```

Comment: That's the idea but can it be done on a list?  Also, I don't mind if it's either onhover or onclick.