# css3 animation on two items in the same time

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div that is absolute positioned on the side of my page. 
It contains an unordered list of items. 
HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Wrapper CSS:

```
#wrapper {  
    /*width: 218px;*/
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:  100px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 31px;
}
```

The reduced width of the wrapper is 31px;
The full size is 218px;
On each of the list items I have set:

```
.menu > li{
    width: 31px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 1s;
}
.menu > li:hover{
    width:218px;
}
```

So that when I hover that `<li>` it reveals all of its content. Obviously it works when wrapper's width is 218px but this way it will go over the page and "hide" some elements on it. I have set the same transition also on the wrapper on hover and it works. Is there another way to do it in a more robust way? This seems to me more an hack than a proper way to do it!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then you could set overflow on the #wrapper to visible instead of hidden? That way, when the li expands when you hover over it, you will be able to see its content - without increasing the size of the wrapper itself

Comment: use `max-width` instead of `width`

Comment: Please give me the fiddle code,so that we also have to work out

Comment: check this answer it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638334/css-jquery-list-of-icons-on-hover-expand-left-to-right/31638688#31638688

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes thanks for the hint. I'll take a look.

Comment: @LukeTwomey you got the point right. This way I didn't have to run the animation on wrapper too. Please will you turn this into an answer so I can vote it?

Comment: @LelioFaieta glad to hear it. I've added the answer for you to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set overflow on the #wrapper to visible instead of hidden. That way, when the li expands when you hover over it, you will be able to see its content - without increasing the size of the wrapper itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use chrome browser.It has a feature that very useful to web developers.

First of all

Open your web page in chrome.

Right click (the portion that you want to make changes) and select Inspect element[Ctrl+Shift+i] in windows platform.

Then u can see like this..

[image: edited web page]

1 I mentioned here is code section and 
2 is css section.

The selected part is highligted in main screen (left side , in my case)

You can find and select the hidden div.

Then make necessary changes to css section that suits your web page and you can see the changes at the real time.

[**!! Please note that this is only for checking and viewing ,so if u make necessary changes,Please copy the edited code and paste it to your original source code also create a backup of your source code before make any changes** ]

Regds..sir

Comment: Thank for your hint but how this is related with my question? Btw I already use this tool but I prefer Firefox with Firebug extension or Firefox Developer edition

Comment: By this method you can find out where the problem was and where the location of each tags.